# How can I switch array to array in object in JavasScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am working on a small project but got a stuck at the one part.

Here is the code.

```
[empty, "Please enter a House", empty × 3, "Please enter a House"]
```

So there are six elements in an array and "Please enter a House" which are first and fifth index is the part that I want to change like this below.

```
    houseManagement: [
        1: { fieldName : "Please enter a House" },
        5: { fieldName : "Please enter a House" }
   ]
```

How can I make houseManagement property get a value of index in forms of an array that holds objects?

Comment: That syntax for arrays doesn't exist. Do you mean having an object with index keys back?

Comment: Yeah that is what I want to have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign the given array to an object after mapping the wanted property.

```js
var array = [, "Please enter a House", , , , "Please enter a House"],
    object = Object.assign({}, array.map(fieldName  => ({ fieldName  })));

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use spread operator,

```
var array = [, "Please enter a House", , , , "Please enter a House"],
var result = {...array}

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array = [, "Please enter a House", , , , "Please enter a House"],
  obj = Object.assign({}, [...array.filter(item => item).map(fieldName => ({ fieldName }))]);

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want an array of objects. You can ignore the code before

```
f=a.map(..
```

since you already have the array.

```js
a= [];
a.length = 5;
a[1] = "please";
a[4] = "please";
f = a.map((e,i) => {if(e){
console.log(i)
let obj={};
obj[i] = {'fieldName':e};
return obj}}).filter(e => e);
console.log('ANSWER:', f);
```